# keybinding build_with with cmd in sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to call a specific build command stored in an external plugin of Sublime. The .sublime.build looks like this.

```
{
  "selector": "text.html.markdown.knitr",
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
  "env": { "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8" },
  "cmd": [ "Rscript -e \"library(knitr); knit('$file', output='$file_path/$file$
  "shell": true,

  "variants":
  [
    {
      "name": "Run",
      "working_dir": "$file_path",
      "shell_cmd": "Rscript -e \"rmarkdown::render(input = '$file')\""
    }
  ]
}
```

It uses cmd to simply call an external command. I would like to create a keybinding that automatically selects the "Run" variant of the .sublime.build. I tried with the following code:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"build_system": "/Packages/knitr/knitr-Markdown.sublime-build", "variant": "Run" }},
```

Unfortunately, the shell returns

```
shell_cmd or cmd is required
[cmd: None]
[dir: /Users/serg/Desktop]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/serg/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin]
[Finished]
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your current build file is invalid, the JSON itself is not valid. I'm not sure if this is a copy & paste error. If not, use a [JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to fix the syntax.

Next, you need to provide the command in the correct syntax. `cmd` is expecting the command as an array. Since your `cmd` is incomplete, I'll provide a different example.

**Wrong syntax**

```
"cmd": ["compiler --arg source.c"]
```

**Correct syntax**

```
"cmd": ["compiler, "--arg", "source.c"]
```

For reference, here's [one of the build files](https://github.com/REditorSupport/sublime-ide-r/tree/master/support) from the R-IDE package:

```
{
    "selector": "text.html.markdown.rmarkdown",
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "cmd": [
        "Rscript", "-e",
        "rmarkdown::render('$file_name', encoding = 'UTF-8')"
    ],
    "osx":{
        "path": "/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the complete answer. This helped a lot!